# VB.NET UWP : How do i get a SerialDevice from a Modem?

Tags: vb.net, uwp, modem

I have a problem to connect to a Telit mobile modem device in my Vb.net UWP Project.

This modem device ( VID: 0x1BC7 , PID: 0x1201 )is recogniced by Windows 10 and shows up in the Device Manager as 5 different devices:

In the COM and LTP Ports Section as :

```
Telit Serial Diagnostics Interface
Telit Serial NMEA Interface
Telit SAP Interface
```

And under Modems as:

```
Telit USB Modem
Telit USB Modem #2
```

In my VB.Net App I created a DeviceWatcher object, which already detects all 5 Devices.

In the next step I try to create a SerialDevice for each of the found devices, but this only works for the first 3 of them.

The Problem is: I need to connect to at least one of two USB Modems to send AT-Commands.

Maybe someone could give me a hint, how to get a SerialDevice from the two Modems or show me a way, how to send AT-Commands to that devices.

In a previously build Win32 app i did this by creating a ManagementObjectSearcher with the Query String "root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem " to find the Modems and then created a SerialPort object with the "ConnectedTo“ property of the ManagmentObject of the Modem.

Maybe theres a similar way in UWP-Apps?

I Added the following Information to the App Manifest:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
<DeviceCapability Name="usb">
  <!--SuperMutt Device-->
  <Device Id="vidpid:1BC7 1201">
    <!--<wb:Function Type="classId:ff * *"/>-->
    <Function Type="name:vendorSpecific" />
  </Device>
  <Device Id="vidpid:1BC7 0036">
    <!--<wb:Function Type="classId:ff * *"/>-->
    <Function Type="name:vendorSpecific" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

To get the devices i created a class which containes a Devicewatcher object

```
   Public Async Function InitHardwareWatcher() As Task(Of Boolean)
        Dim answer As Boolean = True
        Status = "Inititalizing"
        Try
            Await Dlog("Generating Device Watcher", "Orange")


            _DeviceWatcher = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher
            AddHandler _DeviceWatcher.Added, AddressOf OnAdded
            AddHandler _DeviceWatcher.Removed, AddressOf Onremoved
            AddHandler _DeviceWatcher.Updated, AddressOf OnUpdated
            AddHandler _DeviceWatcher.EnumerationCompleted, AddressOf OnEnumerationCompleted
            AddHandler _DeviceWatcher.Stopped, AddressOf OnStopped
            Await StartWatcher()
            Initiated = True


        Catch ex As Exception
            Print_Error(ex)
            answer = False
        End Try
        Return answer
    End Function

    Public Async Function StartWatcher() As Task(Of Boolean)
        Dim answer As Boolean = True
        Await Dlog("Starting Device Watcher", "Orange")
        Try
            _DeviceWatcher.Start()
            Status = "Running"

        Catch ex As Exception
            Print_Error(ex)
            answer = False
        End Try
        Return answer
    End Function

  Private Async Sub OnAdded(watcher As  Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher, deviceinfo As Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation)
        Try
            If InitialScanPerformed = True Then

                Await Log("Devices", "Added Device: " & vbLf & Print_Hardware(deviceinfo), "Green")
                Checknewhardware(deviceinfo)
            Else

                Checknewhardware(deviceinfo)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

When a new device is added i check if it is a Telit device and create a new Object to encapsulate the dhe Telit device with all its Modem Ports.

```
Private Async Sub Checknewhardware(device As DeviceInformation)
    Dim id As String = ""
    Dim iddata() As String = Nothing
    Dim devdata As DevID
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    Try
        'Await plog("Checknewhardware called", Colors.Orange)
        iddata = device.Id.Split("#")
        devdata = Await ParseDevID(iddata(1))

        Select Case devdata.VendorID
            Case "1BC7" '                Telit
                'Await plog("New Hardware is Telit")
                Select Case devdata.DeviceID
                    Case "1201" '        LE 9x0
                        Await Plog("New Hardware is LE9x0")
                        If Global_Modem Is Nothing Then Global_Modem = New LE9x0(device)
                        found = True
                    Case "0036"
                        Await Plog("New Hardware is LE910 V2")
                        If Global_Modem Is Nothing Then Global_Modem = New LE910_V2
                        found = True
                    Case Else
                        Await Plog("Dev ID: " & devdata.DeviceID, "Red")

                End Select
            Case Else
                'Await plog("Vendor ID : " & devdata.VendorID, Colors.Red)
                Exit Sub
        End Select
        If found = True Then Global_Modem.NewDevice(device)



    Catch ex As Exception
        Print_Error(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Within the Class for the Telit device i the try to create a SerialDevice

```
    Private Async Sub Set_device(Device As DeviceInformation)
        Dim outtext As String = "Setting New GPS Serial Device" & vbLf
        Try
            If Device IsNot Nothing Then


            End If
            outtext = outtext & "Getting SerialDevice from Device ID" & vbLf
            _device = Await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(Device.Id)

            If _device IsNot Nothing Then
                outtext = outtext & "     Serial Device Created" & vbLf

                outtext = outtext & "Setting Serial Parameters" & vbLf
                With _device
                    .BaudRate = 9600
                    '.Parity = SerialParity.None 'Parity.None
                    '.DataBits = 8
                    '.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One
                    '.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None
                    '.IsDataTerminalReadyEnabled = True
                    '.IsRequestToSendEnabled = True
                End With
            Else
                outtext = outtext & "     Serial Device NOT Created" & vbLf
            End If

            outtext = outtext & "Trying to create Stream Reader" & vbLf

            _Reader = New StreamReader(_device.InputStream.AsStreamForRead)

            outtext = outtext & "Streamreader Created" & vbLf
        Catch ex As Exception

            Print_Error(ex)
        End Try
        Tlog(outtext, "Green")
    End Sub
```

This works for al the ports except the "Telit USB Modem" and "Telit USB Modem #2". In this case the SerialDevice contains "Nothing"

Thanks for your help

Comment: How do you includes certain device capabilities in your App package manifest? And what is your code to get the SerialDevice? Can you use the vendor/product Id to get the SerialDevice?

Comment: Hi i edited my post to include the relevant parts of AppManifest and the enumeration of the Hardware

Comment: Firstly, in your manifest file, is the “Function Type” correct? Please check if it matches the device. Secondly, are the 2 product ids respectively correspond to the 2 USB Modems(vidpid:1BC7 1201 and vidpid:1BC7 0036)? Thirdly, when creating a **SerialDevice**, is the variate ‘Device.Id’ is not nothing but the variate ‘_device’ is nothing in the code `_device = Await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(Device.Id)`. Lastly, please try to directly use USB APIs to connect the USB modem device. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/talking-to-usb-devices-start-to-finish